# State updates only once react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to build an application that lets users add tags dynamically to any item in the list using a textbox as a child in each array element.

Tags could be multiple, stored as a list: tags : ["X", "Y", "X"]

I am able to update the state as well as render the component the very first time,

for example:

If I add "X" to the tags: Component reflects the tag change immediately

[image]

But after that, when I try to add more tags, it does change in an array, but not renders in Component.

[image]

[image]

The code snippet is below:

Updating state in the parent component: setFilterCopy updates the duplicate variable with the modified values

```
const handleUpdateState = (arrayUpdated) =>{
    setFilterCopy(arrayUpdated)
    console.log(persons)
}
```

Handle event in the child component

```
const handleAddTags = (e) =>{
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        let id_of_array_item = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.add-tag-input').id;
        let tag_val = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.add-tag-input').value;
       
       let tag_value_pre = persons[id_of_array_item-1]['tags']
       
        if(typeof(tag_value_pre) === 'undefined'){
            Object.assign(persons[id_of_array_item-1], {tags: [tag_val]});
        }
        else{
            persons[id_of_array_item-1]['tags'].push(tag_val)
        }   
        handleChange({persons})
      }
}
```

Input code for taking input of tags to be added

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add tags" onKeyDown={e => handleAddTags(e)} id={person.id} className="add-tag-input"></input>
```

State functions:

```
const [word,setWord] = useState("");
const [tags,setTags] = useState([]);    
const [filterCopy,setFilterCopy] =useState([])
const [persons, setStudentProfiles] = useState([]);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should post code as text, not images. Also include a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: At your code there is no call for `handelUpdateState`...

Comment: @Itaywazana it's because its and handler which is being passed to child component  <Lists persons={word.length <1 ?persons :filterCopy} handleChange={handleUpdateState}/>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "SetTags" to update the state?

The content of the array should be "tags", and you need to SetTags every time in your event handler to update the state and then it should rerender.

Comment: -yes I am setting tags property with setTags, and setFilterCopy is to update the overall state for the application. I tried setting setTags field from everywhere of my knowledge, Can you please help dig into it?